# Trouble getting CORS working with Web API 2

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, cors, asp.net-web-api2

I'm having a heck of a time getting Cors working with Web Api. I just created the Web Api with the default template that comes with visual studio 2015. The only changes i made are:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.aspnet.webapi.cors
```

In WebApiConfig.cs::Register(HttpConfiguration config):

```
   var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute(
            origins: "*",
            headers: "*",
            methods: "*");
   config.EnableCors(cors);
```

I made the `POST`  method in the values controller async:

```
public async Task Post(Guid id)
```

I added a small amount of logic to the post method.

I'm calling the Web Api from another project in my solution:

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
      client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("My-GUID",streamProvider.Guid.ToString());
      var response = await client.PostAsXmlAsync("http://localhost.fiddler:2010/api/values", myXmlString);

      if (response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.Created)
      {
            throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError);
      }
 }
```

Request:

```
POST http://localhost:2010/api/values HTTP/1.1
TRS-GUID: 2ca71b41-9e78-4216-a013-e45c6fd6cb4c
Content-Type: application/xml; charset=utf-8
Host: localhost:2010
Content-Length: 183
Expect: 100-continue
Connection: Keep-Alive

<string xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">&lt;?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?&gt;
&lt;root&gt;
  &lt;MbrId&gt;22&lt;/MbrId&gt;
&lt;/root&gt;</string>
```

Response:

```
HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Allow: GET
Content-Type: application/xml; charset=utf-8
Expires: -1
Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-SourceFiles: =?UTF-8?B?Qzpcc291cmNlXEFzeW5jRmlsZVVwbG9hZERlbW9cc3JjXEFwcFxhcGlcdmFsdWVz?=
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Thu, 08 Oct 2015 14:33:08 GMT
Content-Length: 93

<Error><Message>The requested resource does not support http method 'POST'.</Message></Error>
```

Like i said i've made minimal changed and am running this through IIS express locally. I've been googling around and trying a few things but nothing seems to work. I tried adding the cors options as attributes but it resulted in the same thing. I also seen one post suggesting '*' wasn't in the original spec so i tried by using the methods specfically (POST, PUT, GET) but that didn't work either.

**Edit:**
Does this have anything to do with the 'preflight' request? I only notice the POST request in fiddler. I don't see it sending an 'options' request across. If this is the issue shouldn't httpclient handle this automatically?

**Answer**
Thanks goes out to Darrel for the answer. As you can tell the error message coming back was really misleading and definitely sounded like a CORS problem but it wasn't. I never realized CORS was only for the browser. Like Darrell said it was a routing problem. I put a Guid as a POST parameter which caused no route to be matched. To bad the error message coming back couldn't be a little more useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no cross-origin restrictions for HttpClient.  It is purely a web browser constraint.  You do not need to implement CORS for HttpClient requests.

Try making the POST request via fiddler and see if that works.  I suspect you may just have a routing problem.